# Cannot write my code right, because of an error CS0111

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in programming, So i don't know how to fix this error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform zombie;
    public GameObject zombieScript;
    bool canActive = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (canActive == false) { zombieScript.SetActive(true); }
    } 

    void Update()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Distance(player.transform.position, zombieScript.transform.position)));
        if (Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Distance(player.transform.position, zombieScript.transform.position)) <= 10.00000 && canActive == false)
        {
            zombieScript.SetActive(true);
            canActive = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Unity writes:

> Assets\ZombieScript.cs(5,14): error CS0101: The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'ZombieScript'
>
> Assets\ZombieScript.cs(12,10): error CS0111: Type 'ZombieScript'
> already defines a member called 'Start' with the same parameter types
>
> Assets\ZombieScript.cs(17,10): error CS0111: Type 'ZombieScript'
> already defines a member called 'Update' with the same parameter types

in advance, thank u <3

Comment: Do you have two classes `ZombieScript` in your code base?

Comment: The first Google result for "CS0101" explains your error code and how to resolve it. https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206150816-What-is-CS0101-

Comment: no, i do not , but i have variable zombieScript in my code

Comment: how many classes are there in your namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic structure of a C# class looks like this:

```cs
using ...

namespace CompanyXYZ.ProductABC
{
    public class Entity
    {
        // Constructors, properties, methods & etc.
        ...
    }
}
```

[CS1011](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0101) compiler error will be thrown whenever it found more than one definition within the same namespace.

[Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/) allows us to avoid conflict of classes with the same name by grouping them in different namespaces.

In this case, you probably have more than one `ZombieScript` defined under the same namespace which is not shown in your code. Therefore, kindly check if you have it defined somewhere else (within the same namespace) and if found it  you're good to go!